# Django 'startproject' Not Working in Initial Setup

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a project using Django, however I have come across the following error message:

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not
>   properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but
>   settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
>   variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before
>   accessing settings.).

I am using a distribution of Anaconda as my base Python3 install on Windows 10. Here are the exact steps I take in the command prompt:

```
>mkdir test
>cd test
>virtualenv env
>env\scripts\activate
>django-admin.py startproject test .
```

I included the dot at the end of my startproject to create it in the current directory, however this just throws the error listed above. So after googling I tried :

```
django-admin startproject test .
```

taking out the .py for django-admin.py. However, this does nothing, instead my cursor on the command prompt just goes to a new line and blinks. No folder is created and i can't CTRL+C to break it. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: As far as I know test is a python module. I can't create a project called `test` also. Can you try another name? `django-admin startproject <another_name> .`

Comment: Other names yield the same results, `test` was just a place holder name for this post.

Comment: Have you seen https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22949 ?

Comment: Yes, I cam across it while looking for solutions. I tried installing from the Tarball, but pip said it was already installed. Aside from that I'm not sure what the solution was.

Comment: As I understand he installed Django from repo and it worked

Answer (score -2):

To generate a Django project just use the simplest syntax you can come up with, so:

```
django-admin startproject test
```

Also, don't forget to install `django` in your `venv`

Comment: This is the command I used, and a `pip freeze` shows Django 1.8.6 installed